# Negate a word inside a pattern Python & spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have this sentence:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

doc = nlp(u'Non-revenue-generating purchase order expenditures will be frozen.')
```

All I want is to make sure the word 'not' does not exist between will and be inside my text. Here is my code:

```
pattern = [{'LOWER':'purchase'},{'IS_SPACE':True, 'OP':'*'},{'LOWER':'order'},{'IS_SPACE':True, 'OP':'*'},{"IS_ASCII": True, "OP": "*"},{'LOWER':'not', 'OP':'!'},{'LEMMA':'be'},{'LEMMA':'freeze'}]
```

I am using this:

```
{'LOWER':'not', 'OP':'!'}
```

Any idea why is not working?

Comment: What do you mean not working? I reproduced your code and I am getting a match.

Comment: @gdaras how is possible you are getting a match, I am running the code right now and I am not getting any match. Hence my sentence does not include the word 'not' I should get this output: ```purchase order expenditures will be frozen```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example seems to miss a statement that actually performs the match. So I added the method 'matcher.add()' that also verboses a match by calling the self-defined function 'on_match'.

But more importantly I hade to change  your pattern by leaving out your space part {'IS_SPACE':True, 'OP':'*'} to gain a match.

Here's my working code that gives me a match:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)


def on_match(matcher, doc, id, matches): # Added!
    print("match")


# Changing your pattern for example to: 
pattern = [{'LOWER':'purchase'},{'LOWER':'order'},{'LOWER':'expenditures'},{'LOWER':'not', 'OP':'!'},{'LEMMA':'be'},{'LEMMA':'freeze'}]

matcher.add("ID_A1", on_match, pattern) # Added!

doc = nlp(u'Non-revenue-generating purchase order expenditures will be frozen.')
matches = matcher(doc)
print(matches)
```

If I replace:

- doc = nlp(u'Non-revenue-generating purchase order expenditures will
  be frozen.')

  with:
- doc = nlp(u'Non-revenue-generating purchase order expenditures will
  **not** be frozen.')

I don't get a match anymore!

I reduced the complexity of your pattern - maybe too much. But I hope I could still help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
"TEXT": {"NOT_IN": ["not"]}

See
"https://support.prodi.gy/t/negative-pattern-matching-regex/1764"